# How to configure Kafka consumer to process message exactly once?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any configuration for Kafka consumer to read incoming message exactly once ? I want my messages to be in sequence and it should be read exactly once.

Comment: Does https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/ help?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt i looked into configurations but i was unable to find solution

Comment: *Messages to be in sequence*... That's already done for you by Kafka, no?

Comment: There are several other blogs there... Try reading those? https://www.confluent.io/blog/enabling-exactly-kafka-streams/

Answer (score 2):

Since 0.11 version Kafka can be configured to guarentee exactly once by setting processing.guarantee property to exactly_once.

Here is a code snippet to set the property with Kafka's Stream API. 
Hope it helps.

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import java.util.Properties;

Properties config = new Properties();
config.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);

KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);
streams.start();
```

Ref: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/.